# UITableView Expanding and Collapse to show partial or fully Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UITableView that use a commentTableCell which is about 200pixel in height and it has both text and images.

I was hoping when a row is not selected then the height for the row is about 65 pixels which will hide all the images and when the row is expanded to 200 pixels then the commentTableCell will be fully expanded and therefore the images inside the cell would get exposed.

**But the issue I have is when all rows are collapsed to 65pixel in height, none of the images from the commentTabelCell should shown, but I am getting ghost or partial images from the cell shown on some part of the table. Why?**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{            
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

        CommentTableCell *cell = (CommentTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        return cell;    
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {

            return 200;
        }
        else {

            return 65;
        }  
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        //The user is selecting the cell which is currently expanded
        //we want to minimize it back
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            selectedIndex = -1;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            return;
        }

        //First we check if a cell is already expanded.
        //If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
        if(selectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        
        }

        //Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an alternative solution. Try this:

```
// ----------------------------//

// Put this somewhere in your .h file:  
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;  

// ----------------------------//

// Set your default row height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    return 65;  
}  

// In the implementation file:  
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;  

   // Forces the table view to call heightForRowAtIndexPath  
   [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];  
}  

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    // Note: Some operations like calling [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]  
    // will call heightForRow and thus create a stack overflow  
    if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)  
        return 200;  

    return 65;  
}
```